# Hunks failed in Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php SUPEE 8788

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, supee-8788

I'm searching high and low and can't find the solution to my problem.
I almost got the patch working properly except for this file (`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php`).
Excerpt from terminal:

patching file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 43.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 56.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 89.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 126.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 155.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 169.
Hunk #8 FAILED at 304.
Hunk #9 FAILED at 419.
9 out of 9 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Blo                   ck/Product/Abstract.php.rej`

I checked and the file seems to be the same as from stock (no changes made to the core file). Can anyone help?

PS I reverted SUPEE-1533, installed SUPEE-3941 before trying to patch 8788 v2.

PPS it's not duplicate, this issue isn't covered in that post..... please read before you mark it duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried something which worked.. hope it will help others who run into the same problem:

-Download the Abstract.php file

-Add some comment lines

-Upload

-Try patch -> it will fail this time but with different error message:

`patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 48 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 76 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 114 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 166 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 195 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 215 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 356 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 476 (offset 5 lines).
1 out of 9 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php.rej`

-Remove those lines you just added

-Re-upload

-Patch, and it works!